# How to scrape multiple pages with an unchanging url in R?

Tags: r, rvest

That is the [url](https://www.n11.com/magaza/thbilisim/magaza-yorumlari)

My goal is to scrape the review section. But the url doesn't change. Code is given below:

```
url <- "https://www.n11.com/magaza/thbilisim/magaza-yorumlari"

getreviews <- function(master_df){
  as.data.frame(
    read_html(master_df) %>% 
      html_nodes("div.commentContainer p") %>% 
      html_text()
  )
}

reviews <- url %>% 
  map(getreviews) %>%  
  bind_rows()
```

How to scrape multiple pages with the same url?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a Chrome browser, for example, you can figure out the requested URL per page by going to the Chrome development tools (press F12) and looking at the Network pane.

In your example above, you will see that for every page, the requested URL is `https://www.n11.com/component/render/sellerShopFeedbacks?page=page number&sellerId=2145005`, where `page number` is 1, 2, 3, ...

The requested URL pops up on the Network tab when you click on the relevant page number at the bottom of the original URL.

So you just need to increment the page number in your `R` code to see the subsequent pages.

Comment: can you please elaborate on how you found that URL? The link you identify works for me, but if I open the page in Chrome, right-click Inspect, and click on the Network tab, I get a table with 55 rows, and it's not obvious to me how I would home in on any particular element in it.

Comment: I inspected the original URL in the post and when I clicked on page 2 (at the bottom of that URL), the Network tab of the Chrome DevTools popped up the new requested URL (which I posted in the answer above).

Comment: Ah, now I see. I wasn't clicking on the page to refresh the network info; I was just looking at the info for the initial landing page. When I click on "2" with the Network tab open in Inspect, I get just three elements, the first of which is the url. Thanks.

Comment: I got confused until the answer was edited. It's so easy now, thanks.